# Referencing external scripts when page uses NTLM authentication fails

Tags: javascript, c#, authentication, web, ntlm

While incorporating NTLM authentication for an intranet web page we got the following issue.

Our web page code has some javascript files referenced in header

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./jsoneditor.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jsoneditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/ace/ace.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/ace/mode-json.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/ace/theme-textmate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/ace/theme-jsoneditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/jsonlint/jsonlint.js"></script>
```

Some functions from those files are called later in the body of the page.

How it works normally (without authentication). While opening page, there goes a request for index.html, then a separate request for each resource referenced:

[image: Requests seen in Firebug without authentication]

They are processed in order of referencing (you can see that order of files in `<script>` tags is the same as order of requests. How is the .html file processed?

[image: Html file processing]

So there goes a request for resource and parsing is stopped, until the response comes. Then it continues to execution, if any, and moves to next script referenced.

So if there needs to be some order needed like ace.js needs jsoneditor.js to be loaded first, it is ensured.

Ok, that was an introduction, now to the NTLM authentication. It changes the way that resources are fetched because of the NTLM handshake. It looks like this:

```
1: C  --> S   GET ...
2: C <--  S   401 Unauthorized, WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
3: C  --> S   GET ..., Authorization: NTLM <base64-encoded type-1-message>
4: C <--  S   401 Unauthorized, WWW-Authenticate: NTLM <base64-encoded type-2-message>
5: C  --> S   GET ..., Authorization: NTLM <base64-encoded type-3-message>
6: C <--  S   200 Ok
```

So there are 3 requests being sent for a single resource, not one.

Why it matters? Because the web page parser, which sends a request for an external resource, does not care, if it was in fact delivered or not, it just waits for the response (which in our case is 401) and moves to the loading of next scripts. Eventually, all the files come, but (1) the order is not enforced and (2) the call of functions in body may be run, even though resources did not yet arrive (with a successful 200 response). And it may lead to a javascript exception to be thrown and page not being loaded.

[image: Requests seen in Firebug with NTLM authentication]

You can see the proper order of first requests and that responses with status code 200 come mixed.

There are currently two solutions for that we figured out but none satisfies us:

1. When a javascript function in body is executed, enforce some delay (which is not good approach, certainly)
2. Move all the javascript code to index.html and not reference external resources, which is not nice from a code perspective, but ensures that everything runs as expected.

Unfortunately NTLM is designed to authenticate each request separately which complicates the case a bit. Changing NTLM to other authentication is not possible in our scenario.

Is there some way to resolve the issue in a more elegant way?

Just to complete the problem, we are using .NET HttpListener class as our host.

Comment: *"the web page parser, which sends a request for an external resource, does not care, if it was in fact delivered or not"* - sounds like that web page parser is broken. *"the order is not enforced"* - the order in which responses arrive is *never* enforced in HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

For s production app, you should be running a build process before deployment which concatenates and minifies your scripts in any case.  That would eliminate the order problem as they're all delivered as one file with the contents in the correct order.